# JQuery: How to change image after time with fadeIn?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change an image automatically after 2000ms. The image should fade in.

My HTML:

```
<div class="nile-slider large-12 column">
  <img alt="landing page 3" src="assets/Startseite/Slider/Slider_2.jpg">
</div>
```

My JS:

```
// change header image after 2 seconds
var images = ['Slider_1.jpg','Slider_2.jpg','Slider_3.jpg', 'Slider_4.jpg'],
    index = 0, // starting index
    maxImages = images.length - 1;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var currentImage = images[index];
    index = (index == maxImages) ? 0 : ++index;
    $('.nile-slider img').attr('src','assets/Startseite/Slider/'+currentImage).fadeIn('slow');
 }, 2000);
```

With this code the images changes but it does not fade in. How can I force the images to fade in (and even fade out)?

Comment: `.attr` will set the attribute for all the matched elements...`$('.nile-slider img')` should return `invisible` elements to get the `fadeIn` effect..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) using `fadeOut` callback function,  to achieve this.

```
// change header image after 2 seconds
var images = ['Slider_1.jpg','Slider_2.jpg','Slider_3.jpg', 'Slider_4.jpg'],
    index = 0, // starting index
    maxImages = images.length - 1;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var currentImage = images[index];
    index = (index == maxImages) ? 0 : ++index;
    $('.nile-slider img').fadeOut(200, function() {
        $('.nile-slider img').attr("src", 'assets/Startseite/Slider/'+currentImage);
        $('.nile-slider img').fadeIn(200);
    });
 }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Providing the new source as callback of `fadeOut` may do the trick:

```
 $('.nile-slider img')
  .fadeOut('fast', 
           function () {
              $('.nile-slider img')
              .attr('src','assets/Startseite/Slider/'+currentImage)
              .fadeIn('slow');
           }
 );
```